# Event ends in 22 hours? Why not starts in 21 hours?

Tags: bug, status-completed, events

Recently noticed on the front page there is this text:

> Get your Windows 8 questions answered with Doris Chen and Jerry Nixon
>   – ends in 22 hours

Am I the only person who thinks this reads very weirdly. Note also this event hasn't started either.

Shouldn't this read "starts in 21 hours"?

Comment: That depends - does the event end in 22 hours or start in 22 hours? Its current wording is correct if that was the intention (e.g. the event is going on now).

Comment: @Richard, it says starts 23/10 17:00 UTC, i.e. in 21 hours

Comment: He's saying it starts in 21 hours and ends in 22 hours, so its odd to promote it by the end date.

Comment: DOO DEE DOO DEE DOO, NOTHING TO SEE HERE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It now reads correctly. Turns out this was my fault - total PEBKAC - I had the event starting today and lasting 25 hours as opposed to occurring for one hour tomorrow.

Fixed now:

[image: :)]